# Sort Series of Tuples by the second Item in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, tuples

I have a Series of tuples with ID as Index and tuples with coordinates as values. I want order the Serie by Longitude, that is the second element in the tuple.

The function `df.sort_values()` order by first element in the tuple.

Comment: share sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you shouldn't store Latitude / Longitude data *as tuples* in a Pandas dataframe. You lose all vectorised functionality with numeric operations.

Instead, you can split into separate series. This will also simplify your sorting syntax:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LatLon': [(14, 45), (33, 64), (67, 13)]})

res = pd.DataFrame(df['LatLon'].values.tolist(), columns=['Lat', 'Lon'])\
        .sort_values('Lon')

print(res)

   Lat  Lon
2   67   13
0   14   45
1   33   64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select values of select by indexing with `str[1]` and get positions by sorting value by [`argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html), last reorder by seelcting by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
#data from jpp answer
df = df.iloc[df['LatLon'].str[1].argsort()]
print (df)
     LatLon
2  (67, 13)
0  (14, 45)
1  (33, 64)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['LatLon'].str[1].argsort())
0    2
1    0
2    1
Name: LatLon, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This only orders the tuples and when it is reassigned its index is not the same, so it modifies the coordinate of each ID when reassigned the indexes of the unordered serie